# What is the English translation of the artist and title of this artwork? (Characters identified: 吳山作)

Tags: translation

I would like to know who the artist is and what the title of the piece is.

[image: original artwork]

[image: translation required]

Comment: No title in the picture.  The seal said the artist's name is  "吳山" , The written text   "吳山作" means " by Wu Shan"

Comment: @Tang Ho, haha and where did you find those characters? surely not the same as the scribbles im looking at

Comment: @小奥利奥  吳 and 山 are easy to recognize.  As for '作',  it was written in one continuous stroke,   the second downstroke was elongated,  and the last two stokes came back up from the bottom of it.

Comment: I'll take your word for it

Answer (score 4):

The author is certainly 吳山，you can find similar works in [this auction website](https://auction.artron.net/paimai-art5015920324/).

[image]